# Does calling new Object( ); twice make the object created by first call eligible for garbage collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Given:

```
    1. public class GC {
    2.    private Object o;
    3.    private void doSomethingElse(Object obj) { o = obj; }
    4.    public void doSomething() {
    5.       Object o = new Object();
    6.       doSomethingElse(o);
    7.       o = new Object();
    8.       doSomethingElse(null);
    9.       o = null;
    10.   }
    11. }
```

When the `doSomething()` method is called, after which line does the `Object` created in line 5 becomes available for garbage collection?

The correct answer is Line 8.

Why is that? I think it should be Line 7 because new will initiate a new `Object` and then assigned to `o`, which resulted in the `Object` created in Line 5 lose its reference (then become eligible for GC). Am I wrong?

Answer (score 4):

> The correct answer is Line 8. Why is that?

You are confusing the `o` local to `doSomething()` with the `o` that is at the class level. Even though line 7 sets the doSomething() version of `o` to some other reference, you still have the class-level `o` that was set through the `doSomethingElse()` method. You have to null that reference to make it GC eligible, and that only happens by the method call on line 8.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much! I get it now. I didn't notice the local Object o that has shadowed the instance variable, this question was designed to confuse this way i think =.=